# How to do looping in C# programming?

Tags: c#, loops

I have to allow 20 balls to move around the screen. I would like to know how do I use a loop so I would not have to type the codes out long. Currently, the codes I have are

```
for (int i = 0; i < ballSpeedXAxis.Length; i++)
        {
            ballSpeedXAxis[i] = 1;
        }

for (int i = 0; i < ballSpeedYAxis.Length; i++)
        {
            ballSpeedYAxis[i] = 1;
        } 

private void OnUpdate(object sender, object e)
{
Canvas.SetLeft(this.ball1, this.ballSpeedXAxis[1] + Canvas.GetLeft(this.ball1));
Canvas.SetTop(this.ball1, this.ballSpeedYAxis[1] + Canvas.GetTop(this.ball1));
Canvas.SetLeft(this.ball2, this.ballSpeedXAxis[2] + Canvas.GetLeft(this.ball2));
Canvas.SetTop(this.ball2, this.ballSpeedXAxis[2] + Canvas.GetTop(this.ball2));
...
Canvas.SetLeft(this.ball20, this.ballSpeedXAxis[20] + Canvas.GetLeft(this.ball20));
Canvas.SetTop(this.ball20, this.ballSpeedXAxis[20] + Canvas.GetTop(this.ball20));
}
```

ball1, ball2 ... ball3 are images name.

Comment: You've already got an array for ballSpeedAxis. Can't you have an array of ball objects and then have a for loop calling SetLeft & SetTop for each element in the two arrays?

Comment: It seems like you might want to create your own `Ball` class, with properties for the `Image` and `SpeedX` and `SpeedY`. And then have just *one* array to hold all the balls instead of arrays for each value. This class can (and should) encapsulate all the logic for the balls. For example two more properties `PositionX` and `PositionY`, and methods like `UpdateSpeed(int speedX, int speedY)`, `UpdatePosition()` and `Draw(Canvas canvas)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are varying ways.. the most obvious being instead of this:

```
Image ball1;
Image ball2;
Image ball3;
// .. etc ...
```

You would put those in an array also:

```
Image[] balls = new Image[20];
```

..same with your speeds. Then you can change your update method to this:

```
private void OnUpdate(object sender, object e) {
    for (int i = 0; i < balls.Length; i++) {
        Canvas.SetLeft(balls[i], ballSpeedXAxis[i] + Canvas.GetLeft(balls[i]));
        Canvas.SetTop(balls[i], ballSpeedYAxis[i] + Canvas.GetTop(balls[i]));
    }
}
```

Others include putting the already created images into a `List<Image>`.. but that's a bit yuck.

Comment: You should also add an example snippet to illustrate how to add the images into the array.

Comment: @PranavN. That is difficult for me to show.. because the way in which assets are loaded could differ greatly for the OP. For example, are they resources? Are they numbered files in a directory somewhere? I assume the OP can expand on my example to fill in that gap.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead Hi, I would like to know how do I add images into the array. I have tried balls = Image.FromFile("ball1","ball2",...,"ball20");, but I encountered the error "does not contain a definition for 'FromFile'". For your information, I am doing it for Windows Phone 7.1.

Comment: You need to add each image seperately. If they are all named like you showed, you could try: `for (int i = 0; i < balls.Length; i++) { balls[i] = Image.FromFile("ball" + (i + 1)); }`.

Comment: @Corak Hi, I could not implement 'FromFile' as I am doing it for Windows Phone 7.1.

Comment: Well, how do you fill your single variables (`Image ball1`, `Image ball2` and so on)?

Comment: @Corak I do not fill in any single variables for image. I did it by naming the image name in .xaml. An example, <Image x:Name="ball1" Source="/Images/ball1.png" Canvas.Top="480" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.606" >.

Comment: hm... does this [Tutorial](http://www.edumobile.org/windowsphone/windows-phone-programming-tutorials/load-bitmap-image-using-c-code/) help?

Comment: @Corak Thank you, Corak. However, it does not help because if I were to do it that way I have to insert 1 image to 1 canvas which I would have difficulties for my balls to do collision detection in the latter part.

Comment: @LiuJiaHui: XAML might be nice as it wants, but it has it's limitation. There is a point from which creating the objects in code is better and creation of the balls is there.